# Name to a byte[] and download it in javascript

Tags: javascript, download, byte

I write some code in javascript that I create some byte[] and then download it.

For example:

> var byteArray = "data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64,UEsDBAoAAAAIAHyNAkUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGAAAAX3JlbHMvUEsDBAoAAAAIAHyNAkX1IkKh5gAAAEoCAAALAAAAX3JlbHMvLnJlbHOtksFOwzAMQH8l8n11NySE0LJdENJuCJUPMInbVW3jKDHQ/T3hgKDSmHbgGMd+fra83c/TaN455V6ChXVVg+HgxPeh";
>
> window.location = byteArray;

when the browser download this file, the file name is download.xlsx

But I want to get Person.xlsx.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: *"I write some code in javascript that I create some byte[] and then download it."* Interesting. What does that code look like? *"When I download it..."* And that code.

Answer (score 0):

Use HTTP header `Content-Disposition`

`Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Person.ext"`

Answer (score 0):

The question is very unclear, but it sounds like you're creating content server-side that should be downloaded by the browser (rather than opened in a window) and you want to tell the browser what the filename should be.

If that's the case, then you're looking for the `filename` parameter of the `Content-Disposition` header:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Person.ext
```

How you set that header depends on your server-side technology. For instance, in NodeJS (as you said you're using JavaScript), you'd use [`setHeader`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_setheader_name_value):

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Person.ext");
```